# Promoting known properties from record to top level result in Stream Analytics Query

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have a series of dynamic data being processed by a Stream Analytics job. There are a few uniform properties that I can explicitly query for, but the bulk of the payload is of an unknown type at query time. My goal is to take this unknown data (the record) and promote all properties to top-level fields in the resulting query that's written to an Azure Table.

I'm able to flatten the record's properties, it's always added as a child object to the query. `GetRecordProperties()` doesn't help as I don't want a separate record returned for every property.

My query looks like this:

```
WITH 
[custom_events_temp] AS
(
    SELECT 
        [magellan].[context].[data].[eventTime] as [event_time],
        [flat_event].ArrayValue.name as [event_name],
        udf.FlattenCustomDimensions([magellan].[context].[custom].[dimensions]) as [flat_custom_dim]
    FROM [Magellan--AI-CustomEvents] magellan
    TIMESTAMP BY [magellan].[context].[data].[eventTime]
    CROSS APPLY GetElements([magellan].[event]) as [flat_event]
),
-- create table with extracted webhook data
[all_webhooks] AS
(
    SELECT
        [flat_custom_dim].[hook_event_source] as PartitionKey,
        udf.CreateGuid('') as RowKey,
        -- event data
        [custom_events_temp].[event_time],
        [custom_events_temp].[flat_custom_dim].[hook_event_name] as [event_name],
        -- webhook payload data        
        udf.FlattenWebhookPayload(udf.ExtractJsonWebhookPayload([custom_events_temp].[flat_custom_dim].[webhook_payload])) AS [payload]
    FROM [custom_events_temp]
)
SELECT * INTO [TrashTableOut] FROM [all_webhooks]
```

And the resulting record I get looks like this. The idea is to take everything in the `payload` nested object not be nested so each property has its own column in the Azure table.

```
{
  "partitionkey": "zzzzzzzzz",
  "rowkey": "8beeb783-b07f-8a98-ef56-71c43378a5fc",
  "event_time": "2017-10-15T05:37:06.3240000Z",
  "event_name": "subscriber.updated_lead_score",
  "payload": {
    "event": "subscriber.updated_custom_field",
    "data.subscriber.id": "...",
    "occurred_at": "2017-10-15T05:36:57.000Z",
    "data.account_id": "11111",
    "data.subscriber.status": "active",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon": "xxxxxxx",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon_discounted_price": "11111",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon_pre_discount_price": "11111",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.name": "John Doe",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.first_name": "John",
    "data.subscriber.custom_fields.ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "data.subscriber.tags": "tag1,tag2,tag3",
    "data.subscriber.time_zone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "data.subscriber.utc_offset": 120,
    "data.subscriber.created_at": "2017-03-27T18:19:35.000Z"
  }
}
```

Is this possible? The UDF `FlattenCustomDimensions` takes an array of items and exposes them as properties. The UDF `ExtractJsonWebhookPayload` takes a string & converts it to JSON while the UDF `FlattenWebhookPayload` takes the complex JSON object & creates the dot syntax you see in the `payload` object in the results.

My ultimate goal is to get a result set that looks like:

```
{
  "partitionkey": "zzzzzzzzz",
  "rowkey": "8beeb783-b07f-8a98-ef56-71c43378a5fc",
  "event_time": "2017-10-15T05:37:06.3240000Z",
  "event_name": "subscriber.updated_lead_score",
  "payload.event": "subscriber.updated_custom_field",
  "payload.data.subscriber.id": "...",
  "payload.occurred_at": "2017-10-15T05:36:57.000Z",
  "payload.data.account_id": "11111",
  "payload.data.subscriber.status": "active",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon": "xxxxxxx",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon_discounted_price": "11111",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.coupon_pre_discount_price": "11111",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.name": "John Doe",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.first_name": "John",
  "payload.data.subscriber.custom_fields.ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
  "payload.data.subscriber.tags": "tag1,tag2,tag3",
  "payload.data.subscriber.time_zone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "payload.data.subscriber.utc_offset": 120,
  "payload.data.subscriber.created_at": "2017-03-27T18:19:35.000Z"
}
```

Unless someone has a better idea / option.

Comment: if you know all the column names, it may be possible to write a query to promote all nested fields. But the query is going to be big and difficult to change.

Have you considered using [javascript UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions)? It will be much cleaner, you will have to pass in the complete payload in a single field, which you pass to UDF.

Comment: Well yeah, be the point is I don't know the fields. Knowing the field names is easy to address with direct queries using the dot syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the dot syntax into the query where you select * into last line then you can query the columns you expanded in temp into specific columns in the main table